# Email Addresses in Calendar Search

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, search, calendar

Sorry if this question got duplicated.

I use Outlook as a calendar and contact list for my students.  For each meeting that I have with a student I put the class number in the Notes section of the appointment.  If I want to have a review session I can e-mail all of my students who are taking a specific class.

Currently, to let students know about a review session, I do a search in the calendar for the class name, get a list of the students, then go back to my e-mail client and type them one by one.  This can get rather tedious so I'm looking for better solution.

My idea to accomplish this task is to link specific contacts with their appointments.  Then, when I search for a particular class, I'm hoping to list the e-mail addresses in the search results.  I can link the contacts, I can see the contact name after the search, but when I add the e-mail address field to the search results the e-mail address field is blank.

Is there a way to display the e-mail address of contacts in the calendar search?  If not, does someone have another way of performing the task?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing part of the issue but...  Why not create a meeting invitation and send it to each of the necessary students?  Then when you do a calendar search the names will be associcated with the invitation.

Comment: The biggest issue with your suggestion is that I don't use Outlook for my e-mail, just calendar and contacts so it doesn't look like I can create a meeting invitation.  I already have a student associated with their particular meeting so I can get the names to appear.  What I want is to have the e-mail address appear during the search.

Comment: I knew I had to be missing something.

Comment: That sounds like you're as stuck as I am :).